# regex for 0 to 2,000,000,000

Tags: javascript, html, regex, numbers

I have a regex which matches 0-9999999999

^([0-9][0-9]{0,9}|1000)$

I want a regex for 2000000000. I have input boxes in which user should be only allowed to enter numbers between 0 to 2,000,000,000.I am beginner in regex.
I couldn't make the correct regex for it.
How to do it?

Comment: you mean for 2000000000 exactly or 0-2000000000?

Comment: Does it *have* to be a regex? Otherwise you can just parse it to a number and check the value, which will show the intent of the code better.

Comment: Regex is really not suited for this, you can obviously do it but it'll be a long and ugly :) Reconsider it.

Comment: I agree, it's like using a hammer to clean a window

Comment: How much regex do you know? Can you explain the part `|1000`?

Comment: @bub want to match 0-2000000000

Comment: `n=Number("2000000000"); if(0 <= n && n <= 2000000000)`. That's all ...

Comment: Do you want "0000000000" or "000000000" to match? Not to match? Don't care?

Comment: ^([0-1][0-9]{8}|[0-1][0-9]{9}|20{9})$
its starting to match from 100000000
@JaromandaX

Comment: yeah, I knew it was wrong :p - I think `^(\d{1,9}|[01]\d{9}|20{9})$` is closer

Comment: I understand it's not correct way, but believe me guys, it's the only way.

Comment: Do you want "300" to match?

Comment: WOW! It worked.^(\d{1,9}|[01]\d{9}|20{9})$
Thanks @JaromandaX
you rock !

Comment: @JaromandaX Great... now when this question gets old, and all comments are deleted, no-one will know if an answer was accepted, and what it was.

Comment: note, that simple regex allows leading zeros though ... `^(0|[1-9]\d{0,8}|1\d{9}|20{9})$` is better

Comment: @PeterAbolins Jaromanda made sure that there is a decent answer (poking holes into an existing one with me,until it was decent). Only drawback are the leading zeros, but OP has not answered Jaromandas (or my) comment on that, so "don't care" seems a safe bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**
`0` : Just 0
`[1-9]\d{0,8}` : Numbers from 1 to 999 999 999 without leading zeros
`1\d{9}` : Numbers from 1 000 000 000 to 1 999 999 999
`20{9}` : Just 2 000 000 000

**RegExp:**

```
/^(0|[1-9]\d{0,8}|1\d{9}|20{9})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether this is a good approach to solving your problem or not, here is a regex which matches `0-2000000000`.

**UPDATED**

```
^([0-1]?[0-9]{1,9})$|^(2000000000)$
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `(0|\d{1,9}|1\d{0,9}|2000000000)`

Comment: `2000000000` === `20{9}` and is shorter :p

Comment: yeah, but 2000000000 is easier to read than 20{9}  (maybe :) )

Comment: nothing about regex is "easier to read" :p

Comment: It's a kind of programming language too. We should strive for readability . . . . (but I agree)

Comment: Not working!But found answer.
thanks @gregn3

Comment: @KT what was the answer ?

Comment: OK, I see it in the original comments `^(\d{1,9}|[01]\d{9}|20{9})$`